# How To use Simple Html Video Player Also Have Rewind Forward Capability For The Next Video?

Tags: php, html, video, media-player

I am trying to use this code for video in html but fistle it is for flash videos and second thing is that it do not have rewind forward capability for the next video clip

my code is,

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="250" height="250" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"/>
<param name="movie" value="Pro Tools Tutorials.swf"/>
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"/>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<embed src="/unknittingmouse1.swf" quality="high"  align="middle"  bgcolor="#ffffff"  width="250" height="230" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
   </embed>
   </object>
```

we have to also be carefull that that video code will run on internet explorer .

Comment: "rewind forward", you mean switch to the next video ? if so you want to read it from the directory or you want to set yourself a playlist ?

Comment: yes rew/fwd for the next video and it get videos from databse get those videos per user basis ans then rank the video to run accordingly

Comment: checkout jwplayer one of the best cross-browser a/v player http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/ with great addOns http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/?q=playlist+effects

Answer (score 2):

for video
use `jwplayer`
having multiple options

Comment: it d onot require html 5 ? i want for simple html

Comment: It use both but if the browser doesn't support html5 it will fallback to flash, check [the doc](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15991/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at video.js ( http://videojs.com/) add this has all the controls and capabilities wrapped up in a nice package.

Comment: Works with IE6 upwards. Ancient enough for you :) ? Has a flash fall back is needed, all in one wrapper. If you are trying to use "object" then use this as it'll do what you're doing, plus more.

Comment: as i told you that i need for simple html not for html5 !

Comment: This isn't necesarily for HTML5; it's a library that copes with all falvours of HTML. You don;t need ot head up a doctype of HTML5. If you want to strip out any HTML 5 bits (for even those browsers that support it), just grab the flash player. Same for jwplayer (Zuber's answer) - both have flash fall backs that you can strip out and use independently.